# StoryBook - Cannot read properties of null (reading 'babel')

Tags: javascript, typescript, storybook

By `cross-env NODE_PATH=\"src\" build-storybook -c .storybook -o docs` taking an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'babel')
ERR!     at _callee$ (node_modules\@storybook\react\node_modules\@storybook\telemetry\dist\cjs\storybook-metadata.js:194:52)
ERR!     at tryCatch (node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:40)
ERR!     at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:294:22)
ERR!     at Generator.throw (node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:119:21)
ERR!     at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules\@storybook\react\node_modules\@storybook\telemetry\dist\cjs\storybook-metadata.js:66:103) 
ERR!     at _throw (node_modules\@storybook\react\node_modules\@storybook\telemetry\dist\cjs\storybook-metadata.js:68:291)
ERR!     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

While usage of `cross-env NODE_PATH=\"src\" start-storybook` generates StoryBook fine.

Any ideas how to resolve? Thanks in advance

```
// .storybook/config.jsx
module.exports = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.tsx'],
  babel: async options => ({
    ...options,
    presets: [['@babel/preset-react', {runtime: 'automatic'}]]
  })
};
```

Comment: Why is your config file using `.jsx`?

Comment: Mostly because of additional wrappers, but it has no affect